# Jquery show each x seconds

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I try show effects in sequential time , i try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#web_header_ani_ele_1").fadeIn(2000);
    jQuery("#web_header_ani_ele_2").fadeIn(2000);
    jQuery("#web_header_ani_ele_3").show(1000);
    jQuery("#web_header_ani_ele_4").show(2000).delay(3000);
    jQuery("#web_header_ani_ele_5").show(1000).delay(4000);
    jQuery("#web_header_ani_ele_6").show(1000).delay(5000);
    jQuery("#web_header_ani_texto_1").show(2000);   
});
```

But no get show in sequentual time , i try use delay with a time but always show the same time the effects

I don´t know how i can fix this , my idea it´s the first element show and one second after this show the next, other animation after 2 seconds , etc

Regards

Comment: Put each step in the callback of the previous one.

Comment: How i can do that , can you put some example , thank´s

Comment: Use `delay(seconds).fadeIn()`.

Comment: I use delay and always show the same time all effects